# Why is my PHP $_SESSION cleared when doing an AJAX Post?

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, post

I'm trying to get some values from my `$_SESSION` variable but it seems to be cleared everytime an AJAX request is initiated. 
I have pasted the code below, any help much appreciated :

```
/*
 * The input request from angularjs
 */
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

switch( strtolower($data['action']) ) {
  case 'products': getAllProducts($data['fields']);
    break;
  default : echo json_encode(array('success' => false)); 
}
//fb is a firebug debug function, prints PHP vars to console.
fb($_SESSION['var'); //when loading the php file the first time $_SESSION is set
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using AngularJS for my AJAX calls, it works great but now I want to read data from my $_SESSION variable and all I get is an empty $_SESSION. Does this have anything to do with my file_get_contents("php://input");

**SOLVED**

I found the problem, the previous developer did not take into account that one might desire to include files from 2 levels deep :) As such, I scanned through the PHP error logs and saw that a previous script was not loading - this particular script was included with the session_start and $_SESSION variable values.
Checking the error logs will be my first priority from now on

Comment: Are you resetting the session anywhere? Check which PHPSESSID cookie is being sent (and/or cleared)

Comment: You do have session_start() in that execution don't you...?

Comment: I'm assuming that syntax error is because you typed the code out here and doesn't exist in your file. `fb($_SESSION['var');`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the quick comment, I do have session_start(); at the top of my PHP script, the $_SESSION is set the first time when an AJAX call is made but on the 2nd call the $_SESSION is overwritten.

Comment: it's not related to code shown.... only showing us that you can see what's in session doesn't tell anyone anyhting about other code

Comment: Just a tip: If any 404 errors happen, the browser may drop the session so just a heads up :)

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the comments, I found the problem. I scanned through the PHP error logs and saw that a previous script was not loading - this particular script was included with the session_start and $_SESSION variable values.

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer so you can "accept" it

Comment: @GillianLoWong Under what circulmstances could this happen? I really can't imagine a case where it's going to occur but would be interested to know how it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the previous developer did not take into account that one might desire to include files from 2 levels deep :) As such, I scanned through the PHP error logs and saw that a previous script was not loading - this particular script was included with the session_start and $_SESSION variable values. Checking the error logs will be my first priority from now on